# not able to call a codeigniter function using form_open

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

In codeigniter currently I am working on shopping cart but the problem is I am not able to call a function using `form_open` in codeigniter.

However, in the same project in another place same code is working properly but in other view `form_open` it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
<?php if(count($data)):?>
<?php foreach($data as $head_data) :?>
  <div class="row">

 <?php echo form_open('Shopingcart/add',['class'=>'form-horizontal']);?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="imagebox">
          <img src=<?php echo base_url($head_data->p_image)?> class="" alt="picture">
          <h2>New This Week</h2>
          <p>Browse New Portraits and Abstracts</p>
          <p id="id"><?= $head_data->p_id ?></p>
          <p id="p_price"><?= $head_data->p_price ?></p>
          <p id="p_name"><?= $head_data->p_name ?></p>
          <?= anchor('Stuff','View Collections',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])?> 
           <?php

                    echo form_hidden('id', $head_data->p_id);
                    echo form_hidden('qty', 1);
                    echo form_hidden('name', $head_data->p_name);
                    echo form_hidden('price', $head_data->p_price);
                    ?> 
          <p><?php echo form_submit('', 'Add to Cart'); ?></p>  
          <?php echo form_close(); ?>
      </div>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php else: ?>
     <p> No content found</p>
     <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors? If the same code is working somewhere else i guess something is wrong with the way / time you call something.

Comment: No i don't have any errors

Comment: Okay, if no errors are found and if the helper is properly loaded, then your variables must be empty. Have you tried to print_r() the variables to see if they hold any data? EDIT : Do you have any output or completely nothing? For example "No Content Found"

Answer (score 0):

check to see if you are loading the helper.

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

somewhere in your code. preferably in the constructor.
also make sure that error notifications are are turned on, these sorts of problems should give errors that help.

Comment: form helper is loaded in autoload.php and also error notifications are on but i am not getting any error

Comment: just for kicks, add var_dump($data) at the top line of the view.  or put a better conditional in there, like if (is_array($data)) as count can return a number of counting a non-array.

Answer (score 0):

change your code with below one

```
<?php if(count($data)):?>
<?php foreach($data as $head_data) :?>
  <div class="row">

 <?php echo form_open('Shopingcart/add',array('class'=>'form-horizontal'));?>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="imagebox">
          <img src=<?php echo base_url($head_data->p_image)?> class="" alt="picture">
          <h2>New This Week</h2>
          <p>Browse New Portraits and Abstracts</p>
          <p id="id"><?= $head_data->p_id ?></p>
          <p id="p_price"><?= $head_data->p_price ?></p>
          <p id="p_name"><?= $head_data->p_name ?></p>
          <?= anchor('Stuff','View Collections',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary'))?> 
           <?php

                    echo form_hidden('id', $head_data->p_id);
                    echo form_hidden('qty', 1);
                    echo form_hidden('name', $head_data->p_name);
                    echo form_hidden('price', $head_data->p_price);
                    ?> 
          <p><?php echo form_submit('', 'Add to Cart'); ?></p>  
      </div>
      </div>
      <?php echo form_close(); ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php else: ?>
     <p> No content found</p>
     <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: still facing same problem...this solution not working for me

Comment: no any error i am getting even submit button is not trigrring i don't know why